# Hvac unit wiring

Tags: wiring, hvac, capacitor

Was replacing the capacitor to see if I could get my air conditioner to work. This wire came off and I am unsure where it goes. An electrician that came out to check our electric box (long story) thinks it goes here (see picture). Can anyone confirm? [image]

Comment: Should have a wiring diagram for your unit, which you have lost.  Get the make and model number of the unit and google for wiring diagram.

Comment: Did you do any voltage tests, who is who does what

Comment: @Ruskes yes there is power coming out to ac unit. It is humming now. Just need to put this wire back

Comment: @crip659 do have the diagram. Still unsure

Comment: That one is capped off, it does not go anywhere

Comment: Maybe post an image of the wiring diagram (or at least a link to where it can be found. Also, good on you for annotating the picture, however, your big blue lines make it hard to see what's going on. Maybe a 2nd copy of the pic w/o the lines or a better pic showing where that circled wire comes from would be most helpful.